# C#, why I can't add domain user into local group?

Tags: c#, active-directory, dns

Why this code doesn work ? What I want to do is add domain user into local group.

```
DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + "AD1.test.it/DC=test,DC=it"));
srch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=testUser))";            
SearchResultCollection results = srch.FindAll();
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(results[0].Path);

DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
DirectoryEntry dComUsersGrp = localMachine.Children.Find("Distributed COM Users", "group");
dComUsersGrp.Invoke("Add", new object[] { de.Path.ToString() });
```

I get this error: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Simillar code works for adding local user into a local group.

```
DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
DirectoryEntry de = localMachine.Children.Find("testUser", "user");

DirectoryEntry dComUsersGrp = localMachine.Children.Find("Distributed COM Users", "group");
dComUsersGrp.Invoke("Add", new object[] { de.Path.ToString() });
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Is there an inner exception? What does it say?

Comment: Yes, ther is inner exception. "An invalid directory pathname was passed"

Comment: You can't add something with a `WinNT://` prefix into the `LDAP://` tree, I believe. You need to find a way to express that group with an LDAP path, if you want to add it to the LDAP domain

Comment: I wan't to add domain user (LDAP tree) into local group (WinNT tree). So i need to access local group via LDAP ? How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string userPath = string.Format("WinNT://{0}/{1},user", domain, user);
string groupPath = string.Format("WinNT://{0}/{1},group", Environment.MachineName, group);
using (DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry(groupPath))
{
    group.Invoke("Add", userPath);
    group.CommitChanges();
}
```

You need to use WinNT:// ADSI namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You usually have to specify logon credentials to access the directory.  Something like:

```
String domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);
```